# HTML5 <video> element on Android does not play

Tags: android, video, html

Video tags like below plays fine with iPhone, but not Android:

```
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" poster="video/placeholder.jpg" autobuffer controls>
  <source src="pr6.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  <source src="pr6.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
```

With the above code, Android can't even click the clip. It would just see the poster image.

Video tag like below however works with Android:

```
<video src="vpr6.mp4" poster="video/placeholder.jpg" onclick="this.play();"/>
```

However, I still need to multiple sources capability (for Firefox ogv support…). Below code does not work (nor do they work if I stick the javascript into the source tags):

```
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" autobuffer controls onclick="this.play();">
  <source src="pr6.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  <source src="pr6.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
```

With above code, the clip is clickable in Android, but still does nothing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Urg. I despair at the state of the video and audio tags.

Comment: Is this a native or a webpage? If native, have you enabled Javascript for your Webview?

Comment: just a webpage I'm trying to setup so that multiple browsers can play the video correctly.

Comment: @T1000 Can you  solve [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156411/loading-youtube-video-through-i-frame-in-android-webview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove the codecs from the source listings.. It might be that the codecs you're listing are not present on Android, so it's choking.

If you use the src attribute, it'll auto-detect the codec, so it's using something else :)

Comment: That's it! Thank you. It's working perfectly now. With another flowplayer in the source, I can now get the web page correctly play the video on IE, Firefox, Safari, iPhone, and Android.

It makes one wonder why the codec attribute then. To speed things up ?

Comment: one tip for everyone. the onclick="this.play();" is only for Android… Other browsers do not need this to work.

Comment: @Artiom Chilaru Could you jelp me to find what went wrong in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156411/loading-youtube-video-through-i-frame-in-android-webview)

Comment: Can anyone tell me that background video is not showing on chrome browser on mobile device ? url: https://dtlapi.portal.azure-api.net/