# video js does not play video on android device

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, html5-video, phonegap-plugins

I have been using Phonegap and jquery mobile recently. I am doing a sample application in which I want to display a set of videos. I am using VideoJS plugin to view videos. When I run the application on the device, all I see is the video boxes with controls but it doesn't play the video when I click. I use phonegap video player plugins too but could not succeed in playing videos.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911379/html5-video-element-on-android-does-not-play), too, but could not succeed.

Please let me know what could be done.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

code: I'm calling my video like this and i'm not sure where to call the plugin. I hope its correct.

`<div class="video-js-box">
<video class="video-js" controls="controls" onclick="window.plugins.videoPlayer.play(url);">
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        </video>
    </div>`

Comment: Please show how you included the video files. Could it be that the links/src are pointing to a wrong destination?

Comment: What plugin are you using? Do you have a url to it?

Comment: @SimonMacDonald i'm using your video player plugin for phonegap and followed your blog. I'll put the code what i have been using and yes i'm trying to play videos from a remote url.

Answer (score 0):

Well the video tag is broken in the Android Web View so what you are trying to do by placing everything in a  tag just won't work. Instead make it an anchor tag or something similar.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.plugins.videoPlayer.play('http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4')">Play Me!</a>
```

For more info see my blog post on the plugin:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html