# HTML 5 Video Not Showing / Playing in Android

Tags: android, ios, html, html5-video

My HTML 5 video is shows up as a blank white screen in Android galaxy. Online search suggest removing "type" parameter and play via JS, but that does not seem to work.

I tried to recreate the issue with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pf3vdmhg/) but I can't simulate a mobile device.

Any idea how to get mobile video to play on Android and iPhone? I've seen this done by Buzzfeed and the new york times so I know there is a safe way.

```
<section class="video_container sections">
    <video preload="none" autoplay loop muted="true"class="video_window videos">
      <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">
      <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">

        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <div class="video_caption"> 
        <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
    </div>
</section>



$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.videos').each(function(){
      if ($(this).is(":in-viewport")) {
         $(this)[0].play();
      } else {
         $(this)[0].pause();
      }
    })
});

.video_container{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}
.video_captiont{
  position:absolute;
  margin:5px;
  z-index:100;
  font-size:21px;
  padding:3%;

}
```

Comment: https://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2911421/3585278

Comment: I don't have any codecs defined in the src. The Broken Links method is the one I described in the question (removing type and playing though javascript), but that does not seem ot work ( the article is also 6 years old--could be outdated?)